# regex question mark in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

It is probably quite simple, but I do not how to do.

I have this regex :

```
new RegExp("^[A-Za-z\\u00C0-\\u017F][\\- ]?+$");
```

It validates a first name. The name have to begin with a letter (the range is in unicode and works fine) and then continue with letters or - or space. But it can be just letters, as in most names.

I have searched but I didn't find the right way to do it.

I don't want to duplicate the character range. It is just to have a code more "proper".

If you could help, it would be great :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: your expression says "one letter, then optionally either one dash or one space" then if I understand correctly, the `+` is bad syntax, though JavaScript is often forgiving, so... maybe a literal `+`?

Comment: If you want to write a `(?:fast|clean|proper|efficient)` regex, read (and study): [Mastering Regular Expressions (3rd Edition](http://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Regular-Expressions-Jeffrey-Friedl/dp/1565922573). When it comes to learning regex, there are no short cuts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now you only allow *one* letter and then one or more dashes/spaces. You probably want

```
new RegExp("^[A-Za-z\\u00C0-\\u017F][A-Za-z\\u00C0-\\u017F -]*$");
```

But in general, trying to validate a name with regexes isn't such a good idea.

Comment: Yes indeed. But I don't want to duplicate the character range. It is just to have a code more "proper".

Comment: @user1550752: But it isn't duplicate - the second one differs from the first, and unless you also want to allow dashes or spaces at the start of a name, there's no way around that.

Comment: Yes I know, and it works fine with your solution. The fact is I want to use the "?" to have the cleanest regex possible. I know there's easiest ways but I just wanted to see if there is a possibility using "?".

Comment: @user1550752: The `*` (zero or more) already contains the `?` (zero or one). You can't have both. `?+` means something else entirely (possessive quantifiers, not supported by JavaScript anyway).

Comment: Well, ok if you say so.
Thank you for your time